# extension list on tools toolbars

Tags: arcmap, extensions

I'm sorry because my english isn't very good, I hope you're able to understand it. I'm using arcgis 9.3 right now, but when i try the Tools dropdown, then extension, there are no extensions listed. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? I want to use the network analysis extension to finish my project, please help me.

Comment: Full or Custom Install Required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@scw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/143/scw)'s [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/extension-list-on-tools-toolbars) would be the first thing to to try.

I have experienced the empty extension list on a workstation with extensions installed. If memory serves me right, I did a repair on the registry with the ArcGIS Desktop installer and that fixed things.

I think it was: `msiexec /fum setup.msi`.  A complete uninstall/reinstall would have worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the extensions you're interested in aren't installed on the machine? ArcGIS will only list installed extensions. You can add them by visiting the control panel, 'add/remove programs', selecting ArcGIS and clicking 'change' which should allow you to install new extensions (you'll need the installation media to install the extension).

Comment: where to get the media ?